# Override foreign key when assigning via the << operator in a has many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Here is my situation:

```
class Foo
  has_many :bars
end

class Bar
  belongs_to :foo
end

foo1 = Foo.create
foo2 = Foo.create

bar1 = foo1.bars.create
bar2 = foo1.bars.create
```

As you can see, both bars belong to foo1, so their foo_id is `1`. Now:

```
foo2 << bar2
```

I would like this to set bar2's foo_id to `2`. But it seems like if the foo_id is already set (since it already belongs to foo1 in this case) it will not overwrite it. The reason I do not want to assign bar2's foo to `nil` first is that I do not necessarily know the name of the association from that perspective. The actual code looks something like:

```
foo2.bars << bar2
```

I cannot easily perform string parsing because the model type may not correspond to the foreign key. It is also disturbed by the presence of polymorphic associations or STI models. This is why I'd prefer for the above to "just work" without having to arrive at

```
bar2.foo = nil
```

Just because my parent model is of `Foo` class. To be clear, let's say Foo < FooBar. Now even if I were to do something like:

`foo2.class.name.foreign_key` this would evaluate to "foo_id", when the actual foreign key is "foo_bar_id".

Is there a way to force overriding the foreign key when using the `<<` operator?

Comment: Are you calling `foo2 << bar2` or `foo2.bars << bar2`. The latter has the documented effect of updating the `foo_id` on `bar2`, so if that doesn't happen it may be a Rails bug. It's a little tricky to see exactly what you want, since the example is a little too simplified. Is there any chance you could give us an example closer to what you're actually doing?

Comment: `foo2.bars << bar2` does not update `bar2.foo_id` if it is already set. And this is exactly what I'm doing, just replaced class names.